# no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable when using tkinter on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()

app.mainloop()
```

when running python3 I should be getting a window, but I'm getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gui.py", line 2, in 
app = tk.Tk()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2261, in **init**
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

I've done the same thing on uni computers but it doesn't have this issue, so I think its my ubuntu setup. Is anyone experiencing this issue or knows how to solve it?

Comment: So, is a `DISPLAY` environment set in the terminal from which you ran the command? what kind of Ubuntu setup are you running (desktop, server, WSL?)

Comment: I got Ubuntu from the Win10 app store so it's WSL.

Comment: So WSL is a commandline-only interface - you *can* get it to interact with the (Windows) graphical display but it requires extra software. See for example [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)